# Where clause returning too many results

Tags: sql

I am not sure why my where clause is not working perfectly. In the script I am using it with a `where` clause.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (myvalue VARCHAR (50))

INSERT @TABLE
    SELECT 14 UNION ALL
    SELECT 16.5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 19 UNION ALL
    SELECT 24 UNION ALL
    SELECT 26 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 555

SELECT DISTINCT M.myvalue 
FROM @TABLE M
WHERE 
     (M.myvalue < '6' OR M.myvalue > '28'  OR M.myvalue IS NULL)
```

In the output I am expecting 2 and 555, but when I ran the query it's returning all the values:

```
myvalue
14.0
16.5
19.0
2.0
24.0
26.0
555.0
```

Can anyone please correct me?

Comment: **Don't use** `varchar` for numerical values!  Those are **numbers** - use a `decimal(10,2)` datatype (or whatever is suitable) - don't store them as a **string** !! Since you're using a `varchar` (string) - **ALL** the values are less than `6` - none start with a digit of 6 or more....

Comment: the reason of using varchar for numeric, is because some the value will be like 125.52xyz

Comment: @KartikSharma Please consider accepting an answer to *this* question, and asking a new one about the *actual* situation with such values. In that question, clearly indicate how it's different from this one, explain *why* you need those types of values, and what you've done/researched to solve your issue yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing it with a string with the quotes around '6' and '28'

It should be:

```
WHERE ( 
  M.myvalue < 6 OR M.myvalue > 28  OR M.myvalue IS NULL)
```

Also, as others pointed out, `myvalue` column should be numerical or else you are comparing string to a number.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (myvalue DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: ***AND*** the table should contain a value of a **numerical** datatype, too! Not string ....

Comment: when i am removing quotes, i am getting conversion error.  Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int

Comment: @KartikSharma As others pointed out, you are storing them as string. You should use `DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (myvalue DECIMAL(10,2))`

Comment: @Robin: the reason of using varchar for numeric, is because some the value will be like 125.52xyz

Comment: @Robin: the reason of using varchar for numeric, is because some the value will be like 9 And 9.5
9 And 10
Any suggestion please

Comment: @KartikSharma I think you can do that with the use of `replace()`